# How to return Completed status on RxJS Observable in Angular

Tags: angular, observable, rxjs5

I've imported EmptyObservable like this:

```
import { EmptyObservable } from 'rxjs/observable/EmptyObservable'
```

I then assigned it to an object like this:

```
public user = { initCompleted: new EmptyObservable() }
```

Both lines validate in Visual Studio Code, the library appears to be found, and no warnings are shown. Based on that, I hope I am on the right path...

Now, when an API call I'm making is done and the results are assigned to a few values on the user object, I want to emit the Completed signal. How do I emit the Completed signal using the EmptyObservable in Angular 6, using RXJS 5.5.6?

I was able to make this work using `Subject` observer/observable by simply subscribing to `user.InitCompleted` and waiting for any value from `user.initCompleted.next(somevalue)`, but I'm fairly certain this is not the best tool for the job.

Comment: You're not on the right track. First, RxJS6 is out, and Angular 6, too, and there is no EmptyObservable anymore. Second, An empty observable never emits anything, and completes as soon as you subscribe. Second, you can't emit events programmatically from an observable: that's what subjects are for. But finally, it seems like your design is really awkward: you shouldn't return an empty user object and then emit when it's initialized. You should instead return an Observable<User>.

Comment: Thank you, JB. I'm still new to Observables, and they are an afterthought to me - when something ends up being async and causing me grief. Your idea for simply creating an Observable<User> is what got the light on for me. I'll work towards that - but maybe I'll update RXJS first :D Thank you for steering me in the right direction.